# how to change orientation of TabBar and Navigation Controller in Ipad App ..?

Tags: iphone

when i load tabbar and navigation bar then tabbar and navigation bar is not oriented with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that in every single ViewController in your project there is a method like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: i make it sure that this method is like this but when i change the orientation then tabbar and navigation bar is not rotate

Comment: if this method is in ALL your UIViewController-subclasses your views should rotate. When you say tab and navBar do not rotate, does the rest of the view rotate? Or no rotation at all?